# How to Fetch MySQL all table data using GraphQL

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express, graphql

I am new in GraphQL so I want to fetch MySQL all table data in Express server and then push it to ReactJS. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Connect Knex to DB in (db/db.js):

```
const config = require('../../config/config');
const knex = require('knex')(config.config);

module.exports = knex;
```

Require GraphQL and Knex (DB):

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const knex = require('./db/db');

const { 
    GraphQLObjectType, 
    GraphQLString, 
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLList,
    GraphQLNonNull
 } = graphql;
```

Let's say you have a book type:

```
// Your book type
const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Book',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        genre: { type: GraphQLString },
    })
});

// Prepare query to get all books, I used Knex query builder with MySQL
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType', 
    fields: {
        books: {
            type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
            async resolve(parent, args){
              const books = await knex('books');
              return books;
            }
        },
    }
});
```